# How to add data in Datagridview from a class to another class?

Tags: c#, wcf, datagridview, callback

I am currently working with a WCF application. I must display the data received from callback in a DataGridView. These are my codes:

From FrmMain form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InstanceContext callbackInstance = new InstanceContext(new StockExchangeUpdates());
        SubscribingClient.RegisterSubscriberServiceClient proxy = new SubscribingClient.RegisterSubscriberServiceClient(callbackInstance);
        proxy.RegisterSubscriber(Guid.NewGuid());
    }
```

Class StockExchangeUpdates

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class StockExchangeUpdates : IRegisterSubscriberServiceCallback
{
    int ctr = 0;
    FrmMain main = new FrmMain();
    public void passGeneratedNumber(int num)
    {
        try
        {
            ctr = ctr + 1;
            main.dgRandom.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss"), num, ctr);
            // this is not working..
            // Error: "dgRandoms" is inaccessible due to its protection level

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I got use to try different ways but it is still not working. Please help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry typo .. // Error: "dgRandom" is inaccessible due to its protection level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to set a different "Modifier" on your DataGridView.
That is, in the properties window for "dgRandom", change the property "Modifiers" to "Public" (or "Internal", if that is enough). If it is set to "Private", it will only be "seen" from within the same class.

(Edit: I assume you are using Windows forms and not WPF)